# Hide $0.0 with free Shipment Method

Tags: shipping

How do I hide amount $0.00 when free Shipping Method is applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to a `css` file which is applied on the checkout page:

```
 .opc-shipping_method #s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping span.price {
      display: none;  
 }
```

What I'm doing is just hiding the element on the page which contains the price. In this case it's a span within an element with the id `#s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping`. `display: none;` makes it disappear completely.